# Is sql injection possible with file_get_contents("php://input");  or it is possible just with get and post?

Tags: php, sql, flash, code-injection

I have a website that communicates with an embedded swf object.
The flash runs sendAndLoad("URL", receiver) command to transfer xml strings with server and the server uses file_get_contents("php://input") to receive xml string from flash . Should i worry about sql injection attacks?

Comment: _any_ and all data is suspect, but for SQL-injection, this is beside the point. Valid data can contain quotes, valid data can contain a string `'; ALTER TABLE` if for instance in some blog about SQL. Always use the methods provided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: Yes

A bit longer answer: While it's not instantly obvious, a request CAN be forged and cause injection if the data isn't escaped properly. Just because the data usually comes from a flash object doesn't mean one can't create his own script to send malicious data.

Comment: I will not place that string directly in the sql query ,i use a xml parser for parsing the incoming xml and fetch some variables , is that still dangerous?

Comment: Yes. One could send valid XML with 'malicious variables'. While this takes far more effort than your usual SQL injection, it's still possible. As a general rule of thumb: Whenever something comes from the user, escape it the best you can.

Comment: The flash have some limitation that avoids cross-domain access to a resource. I need to know whether a php server accepts xml string just from a swf file in same directory or not?